# How to install GnuPlot on windows?

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin, mingw, gnuplot

A Unix (mac/Linux) user who has been forced to work on a windows machine here :)

I have scripted loads of work in GnuPlot and don't want to switch to other programs at this moment. I would appreciate it if you could help me know how to install GnuPlot On windows (more specifically windows 10). questions:

1. I know there are two options according to [this page](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html), Cygwin and MinGW. which one is better?
2. I have MinGW installed and I know I need to install one of the options from [this page](http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/gnuplot/Eng/winbin/) but I don't know which one(s)! and how.
3. I have searched the internet but it seems most of the search results are for compiling. I don't want to go through compiling and all the hassle.
4. I tried installing the binary from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2055), and when I try to run the program this is the error I get:

> Unable to execute file:
>
> C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\wgnuplot.exe
>
> CreatProcess failed; Code267.
>
> The directory name is invalid.

[image]

I would appreciate it if you could give me a very simple stepwise installation (1 2 3 ...), preferably with visuals, and instructions.

**P.S.** A nice way to install Free, Libre, and Open Source Software (FLOSS) on Windows and keep them updated, is to use package managers like Chocolatey. There are GnuPlot chocolatey packages [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages?q=gnuplot). Just install choco as instructed [here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation). Then use `choco install Gnuplot` to have the software installed.

Comment: If you are comfortable with Linux, why not take advantage of Bash On Windows? It's super easy to install gnuplot on the Linux subsystem and it works just fine with full capabilities.

Comment: Well, unfortunately due to the stupid university policies I'm not able to install bash! BTW, if I do install bash then can I run GnuPlot plotting through that? I thought it is just command line.

Comment: You are not allowed to enable the linux subsystem on your windows machine? It would be a wonderful experience to work with gnuplot on the linux subsystem. If this isn't an option for you and you must run in on windows, then I'll try to put together something. But are you sure you aren't able to use Bash On Windows? It doesn't require installing bash, just enabling a windows feature.

Comment: There are two different ways to install bash, first to install the creators update, which requires an upgrade permission, which is blocked for me! second to activate the developer mode. that's also blocked for me. I have reported this to our help desk. yet to recite a respond on that.

Comment: Ah, ok let me try to figure out how to install it on windows then; I'd done it before and it worked.

Comment: @Ptheguy It would be your kindness to help me with the instalation

Comment: The PS comment about Chocolatey has a broken link and points to software that only talks about Windows 7. Seems to be outdated stuff.

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo thanks. I think it should be fixed now.

Comment: AFIK, there is a port of gnuplot available in the cygwin distribution. Perhaps this would be an option ....

Comment: @user1934428 sure. please share a link.

Comment: Just run the usual Cygwin Setup and enter _gnuplot_ in the search field! BTW, from my understanding, you will have to install Cygwin/X for this, which gives you an X Window System on top of Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to install MinGW or Cygwin. Actually packages compiled in MinGW are compatible with Windows. Just download the binary of `gnuplot` from [Their repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/) and you are good to go.

Additional points:

- When installing, check which terminals you want to set up; also
  check if you  want the installer to add the `PATH` variable to your
  system. Also, create a desktop shortcut.
- After installation, you should see the desktop shortcut. Clicking on it should open a terminal-based `gnuplot` (which hopefully you are familiar with).

Please note that I have used the `x11` terminal (you can get this working by installing [xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)). There are other options such as `windows` and `qt` terminals, but I am not an expert on using these.

Comment: So I don't need to install MinGW?!

Comment: All the packages and dependencies should be installed through the installer! Can you give this a try and tell me if it works or not? Unfortunately, I can't carry out the process on my laptop now as it would interfere with my setup on the Linus subsystem.

Comment: It worked. The error I mentioned in the OP appears anyway the first time. But next times it works just fine.

Comment: Awesome. If you think my answer was useful, you can upvote and accept it :)

Comment: I installed gnuplot using a Windows .exe installer. Works fine with `cmd`, but hangs when I call it from Git Bash. Does anybody have gnuplot working from Git Bash ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have Administrator rights on this machine.
Right click on MinGW, Run as Administrator, install -  should be OK.
Good luck!
BR, Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$~ scoop install gnuplot

Installing 'Gnuplot' (5.4.5) [64bit] from main bucket
gp545-win64-mingw.7z (37.7 MB) [=======================================] 100%
Checking hash of gp545-win64-mingw.7z ... ok.
Extracting gp545-win64-mingw.7z ... done.
Linking ~\scoop\apps\Gnuplot\current => ~\scoop\apps\Gnuplot\5.4.5
Creating shim for 'gnuplot'.
Creating shortcut for GNUPlot (wgnuplot.exe)
'Gnuplot' (5.4.5) was installed successfully!
```